# Holomorphic function with bounded real part

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic over $|z| \leq R$, for some positive $R$, and that $f(0)=0$. Further, suppose that $Re(f(z)) \leq C$ for all $|z| \leq R$. How do we show that $|f(z)| \leq \dfrac{2Cr}{R-r}$ for all $|z| \leq r$, for any $0 < r < R$? Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a similar estimate if you know that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant K$? Can you biholomorphically map a strip into a disk?

Comment: sorry, but still to no avail...

Comment: What about mapping the hal-plane in question conformally onto the unit disk using a fractional linear transform such as $\displaystyle S(z) = \frac{-z}{z - 2C}$? This has $S(0) = 0$. Now look at the composition, which takes $z = 0$ to ... What about the map $z \mapsto S(f(Rz))$?

Comment: @bryanj, I already edited the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I'm sort of just learning the subject myself, but it seems to me that the two main tricks for problems which have a flavor similar to this one are 1) Write out a representation of something using the Cauchy Integral Formula, and 2) Find a way to use a Maximum Modulus Theorem / Schwarz Lemma type argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S(z) = \displaystyle \frac{-z}{z - 2C}$. Then $S(z)$ maps $\Re z < C$ conformally onto the unit disk with $S(0) = 0$. Then the composition $g(z) = S(f(Rz))$ maps the unit disk into the unit disk with $g(0) = 0$.

We can apply the Schwarz lemma to conclude that $|g(z)| \le |z|$ on the unit disk. This corresponds to
$$ \Bigg| \frac{f(z)}{f(z) - 2C} \Bigg | \le \Bigg| \frac{z}{R} \Bigg |$$

From this you get (using the triangle inequality, etc.)

$$|f(z)| \le \frac{|z|2C}{R - |z|}$$

The final inequality follows from $a < b < R \implies \frac{a}{R-a} < \frac{b}{R-b}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm studying your proof. =)

Comment: Ok, I think, I get it now :)

Comment: It seems the meat of this solution comes from picking the proper $S$.  Could you add a bit more about where it comes from?

Comment: Its a Möbius transformation (fractional linear transformation). You can always map a half plane to the unit disk using one of these. $T(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ is a standard one. Pre-compose with rotations and transations if necessary.